# How to get the local reference value from a template driven form tag dyanamically in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

Below is my template driven form.

I want to get the local reference name (`#{{obj.sample_name}}`) in the `*ngIf` to show error message. how to achieve this?

```html
<form class="theme-form" name="sample" #sample="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let obj of items">

    <input type="text" 
           class="form-control" 
           [(ngModel)]="obj.sampleValue" 
           name={{obj.sample_name}} 
           #{{obj.sample_name}}="ngModel" 
           [range]="[1, 12]">

    <p *ngIf="{{obj.sample_name}}.errors?.range">
      error message
    </p> 
    <!-- I want the name of the dyanamic form reference here to show errors -->

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is `range="[1,12]"` custom directive?

Comment: ya it is from  .. ngx-custom-validators ..

Comment: I might be wrong about the syntax of dynamic variable names for angular, but try: `this[obj.sample_name].errors?.range`

Comment: you needn't (use the same for all, e.g. #sample="ngModel") Angular know what element you want:https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope